# How to add a condition in select class, based on the result value of another select class

Tags: postgresql

- I need a Postgres query to get "A value", "A value date", "B value" and "B value date"
- The B value and date should be the one which is between 95 to 100 days of "A value date"

I have the query to get "A value" and "A value date", don't know how to get the B value and date by using the result (A value)

```
select u.id, 
      (select activity 
       from Sol_pro 
       where user_id = u.id 
       and uni_par = 'weight_m' 
       order by created_at asc 
       limit 1) as A_value 
from users u;
```

1. the B_value and B_date from the same sol_pro table,
2. 95-100 days after the A_value date (if more mores are there between 95-100, I need only one(recent) value) Expected

**Output:** id = 112233, A_Value = "weight = 210.25", A_value_date = 12-12-2020, B_value = "weight = 220.25", B_value_date = 12-12-2020

Comment: Please review [ask]. Following that a a template for your question greatly enhances you chance of getting a satisfactory answer. Here a couple additional questions. What is the source for B_value and B_date; also table Sol_pro or another table?. As for range 95-100 days for B_date, is that 95-100 days before A_date? 95-100 days after A_date, either before and/or after, range 95 days before and 100 after, other possibilities? Please Post sample input date - as text **no images**, and the expected output of that data.

Comment: Hi @Belayer, thanks for the suggestion, sure will check it out. for your above question 1) the B_value and B_date from the same sol_pro table, 2) 95-100 days after the A_value date (if more mores are there between 95-100, I need only one(recent) value)


Expected Output:
id = 112233,
A_Value = "weight = 210.25",
A_value_date = 12-12-2020,
B_value = "weight = 220.25",
B_value_date = 12-12-2020

Comment: OK, it is a start. I copied this answer to the question. In the future please don't put answers in a comment, put them in the original question. But where are the table description and **input** data. Output without the input that produced it is not very useful. Also, the layout of that input (table DDL) is very useful. Perhaps, I'll try something but no guarantee.

Comment: Your output is inconsistent with your description: Description says B_date should be 95-100 days after A_date. But your output has the same date for both 12-12-2020. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Well without table definition I developed it from the output columns and your original query. Further I had to make up stuff for the data, but the following should be close enough for you to see the technique involved. It is actually a simple join operation, just that it is self-join on the table sol_pol. (I.e it is joined to itself). Notice comments indicated by --<<<

```
select distinct on (a.id)
       a.id
     , a.user_id                         --<<< assumption needed 
     , a.activity "A_value"
     , a.created_at::date "A_date"
     , b.activity "B_value"
     , b.created_at::date
  from sol_pro  a 
  join sol_pro  b
    on (    b.user_id = a.user_id         --<<< assumption  
        and b.uni_par = a.uni_par         --<<< assumption  
       )
 where a.id = 112233                      --<<< given Orig query
   and a.uni_par = 'weight_m'             --<<< given Orig query, but not needed if id is PK
   and b.created_at between a.created_at + interval '95 days'  --<<< date range inclusive of 95-100
                        and a.created_at + interval '100 days' 
  order by a.id, b.created_at desc;
```

See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cbfa323fd5599906059a9460266913d6) for example run. The example contains a column you will not have "belayer_note". This is just a note-to-self I sometimes use for initial testing.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have tables `users` and `measures`:

```
# create table users (id integer);
# create table measures (user_id integer, value decimal, created_at date);
```

They are filled with test data:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO measures VALUES (1, 100, '9/10/2020'), (1, 103, '9/15/2020'), (1, 104, '10/2/2020');
INSERT INTO measures VALUES (2, 200, '9/11/2020'), (2, 207, '9/21/2020'), (2, 204, '10/1/2020');
INSERT INTO measures VALUES (3, 300, '9/12/2020'), (3, 301, '10/1/2020'), (3, 318, '10/12/2020');
```

Query:

```
WITH M AS (
  SELECT
    A.user_id,
    A.value AS A_value, A.created_at AS A_date,
    B.value AS B_value, B.created_at AS B_date
  FROM measures A
  LEFT JOIN measures B ON
    A.user_id = B.user_id AND
    B.created_at >= A.created_at + INTERVAL '5 days' AND
    B.created_at <= A.created_at + INTERVAL '10 days'
  ORDER BY
    user_id, A_date, B_date
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) * FROM M;
```

will select for each user:

- the first available measurement (A)
- the next measurement (B) which is made between 5-10 days from (A).

Result:

```
user_id | a_value |   a_date   | b_value |   b_date
---------+---------+------------+---------+------------
       1 |     100 | 2020-09-10 |     103 | 2020-09-15
       2 |     200 | 2020-09-11 |     207 | 2020-09-21
       3 |     300 | 2020-09-12 |  [NULL] | [NULL]
(3 rows)
```

P.S. You must sort table rows carefully with `ODRDER BY` when using `DISTINCT ON ()` clause because PostgreSQL will keep only first records and discard others.